# url rewriting to redirect to correct javascript file version

Tags: javascript, versioning

I recently read on Meta about some browser not flushing their cache even after reading a script url of this form

**myscript.js?v=1234**

so to go around the problem i am thinking about implementing a solution i also read but without any details given to it. something like **myscript-1234.js** and reroute to the actual correct file, but i have a doubt now.
Should i rewrite that url to **myscript.js** or to **myscript.js?v=1234**   ? I am actually confused as to how it even going to make a difference to have a rewriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewriting should not redirect to any other URL *(which would the be fetched by the browser)*, but should be "internal" on your server.

What I mean is that when receiving a request for "`myscript-1234.js`", your server should instead serve the content of the `myscript.js` file ; which will always be the last version.

In the end :

- For the client the is a different URL each time you update the file on the server : `myscript-1234.js`, `myscript-1235.js`, `myscript-1236.js`, ...

  - This is why the browser will try to re-fetch the file from the server : as it's not the same name, it will not have the file in cache
- But, for the server, there is always one and only one file : `myscript.js`
- And you're using some "rewrite" rule so thr server just removes the `-XYZ` portion of the file name before trying to read it from disk.

Comment: thank you for your help! it makes sense! i just finished implementing it!